# Call modules without needing a local tf file?

Tags: terraform

I have this tf file:

```
variable "var1" {}
variable "var2" {}

terraform {
  backend "s3" {
  }
}

module "my-module" {
  arg1 = "${var.eb_application_name}"
  arg2 = "${var.eb_environment_name}"
  source = "git::ssh://git@bitbucket.org/blah/my-module.git//my-sub-module
}

output "myoutput" {
  value = "${module.my-module.myoutput}"
}
```

I run these commands from the console:

```
terraform init -backend-config='region=us-east-1' -backend-config='key=mykey' -backend-config='bucket=mys3-bucket' 
terraform apply -var 'var1=balh' -var 'var2=blah'
```

I'd like to do all of this from just a console command, including calling my module. Looking at my tf file, can i do all of this with just arguments to terraform or do i have to have a tf file? Perhaps there is a way to pass in a tf file as raw text (like an environment variable)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got what you need.

You can define the variables for each module, such as:

```
variable "my-module-enable" {
  default = true
}
```

then use `count` as switch to enable or disable this module.

```
module "my-module" {
  count = "${var.my-module-enable ? 1 : 0 }"
  arg1 = "${var.eb_application_name}"
  arg2 = "${var.eb_environment_name}"
  source = "git::ssh://git@bitbucket.org/blah/my-module.git//us-east-1"
}
```

Then you easily control it via terraform args

```
terraform apply -var 'my-module-enable=false'
```

Comment: hmm but then I still have a file- the "tfvars" file. I was wondering if it was possible to totally avoid a local file and pass EVERYTHING to the terraform command as args directly

Comment: With `-var-file`, you can still add other variables args  with `-var 'var1=balh' -var 'var2=blah'`

Comment: but `-var-file` still needs to point to a file right? maybe im misunderstanding something, but my hope was to have my module in source control and be able to call it by passing command line args to the terraform program without having a local file at all. I want to be able to do `module "my-module" {..}` totally from command line args too

Comment: @red888 I updated the answer, let me know if this is what you ask for.

Comment: hmm not really, maybe I didn't phrase the question right or I'm being obtuse about this. I just want to not have a local file that calls my module, I want to pass everything in via command line to call the module which lives in source control- no local files. Maybe I can pipe the tf file text directly to the terraform command?